# More efficient way of measuring nanosecond performance/speed of printf and std::cout [C++]

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I am measuring the amount of time printf and cout are for a given output (a number), and want to know if there is a better way of measuring nanosecond precision in C++ (or if this code needs improving).

```
int rand1 = rand();
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
printf("%d", rand1);
auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
double secondsPrintf = (double)std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(finish-start).count();
auto start1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::cout << rand1;
auto finish1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::cout << endl; // measuring performance of printing the number, no need for endl (drastically lowers performance)
double secondsCout = (double)std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(finish1-start1).count();
```

I heard chrono's now() function is very precise, but is there a better way (or more efficient, quicker, etc.) to do any of these operations?

Comment: `std::cout` should be *theoretically* faster than `printf(const char*, ...)`, because it doesn't have to evaluate the variable arguments. Rest is implementation defined

Comment: Thanks for your comment @iammilind. Is there a source on that I can read more about?

Comment: Is the question really just about timing?  It doesn't seem to really have anything to do with cout/printf at all.

Comment: It's about how many nanoseconds it takes to print out a random integer.

Comment: If you find a more fine-grained way to measure performance on your system, report it to the implementers of your standard library.

Comment: Printing N numbers in a loop and dividing the time by N will give you better results.

Comment: I doubt that you will be able to get real *nanosecond* precision timings this way. While the precision of the function might be nanoseconds, I doubt that the accuracy is close to that.